# How to use Mac keyboard while Simulator keyboard is on the screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

We can connect our Mac keyboard in Simulator using this:

Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard

However, then the keyboard on our simulated iPhone device hides. Is there a way to use Mac keyboard while the simulated iPhone keyboard is still on the screen?

Comment: Yes ,Once keyboard hide you can press CMD + K then keyboard shown and then you can .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks the others for asking but "*Uses the Same Layout as macOS*" didn't change anything in my case.

The solution was to check "*Connect Hardware Keyboard*" and then "*Toggle Software Keyboard* (**command+K**)".

Answer (score 1):

1.you connect keyboard press **Shift+command+k**

2.press **command+k** for both **show** and **hide** keyboard.

3.you can also use this type.

--> select **simulator**

--> Go to **hardware** -> **keyboard**

--> check **Uses the same layout as macos** and **connect hardware keyboard.**

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

Yes, you can connect and use your Mac keyboard while simualtor keyboard is on the screen

[image]